# What framework should i chose for make mobile game?

Tags: mobile, 2d-games

Hi i want to make andriod/ios game. it will be simple RPG base click game like Shakes and fidget. I wonder what app will be best to do it. So farn i know javasript well and java on low level. I find gap mobile could be good, because of my knowlidge of javascript. But unity looks good too, problem is i never done nothing in C# or unity. What is your experience and opinions?.

I know my english is bad, so i apologize for that.

Comment: *"i delete this post after a got answers"* - I'd suggest you take the [tour], because if you think that's a good thing you clearly do not understand the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Unity 2D with C# and it's works really well for me. I suggest you to learn C# if you want to go with Unity(which I think is a really good option) but you can use javascript with Unity too if you don't want to learn C# but I don't know if this feature is still usable.

Comment: i got advantage that javascript is simalar with C#, but still i need start somwhere so are there any free and usefull tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

You can just search unity 2d tutorials at youtube if you want free tutorials (My advices are Brackeys and Blackthornprod) or you can use sone online learning websites like Udemy (which I used to learn unity and which helped me a lot)